# Openconnect profile add and automate VPN connectivity

Tags: 16.04, networking, vpn, openconnect

I use **Cisco anyconnect** in Windows machine at office laptop. I also do office work from home with my personal **Ubuntu** laptop. Normally to connect I use `openconnect` which works perfectly. Installing `openconnect` is quite easy but to connect  I follow below steps:

1. `sudo openconnect https://xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd`
2. I provide sudo password. Then I get below messages:

   ```
   POST https://xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd/
   Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443
   SSL negotiation with xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd
   Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
   Certificate from VPN server "xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd" failed verification.
   Reason: signer not found
   Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:
   ```
3. I type yes. Then I get below messages:

   ```
   Connected to HTTPS on xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd
   Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
   GET https://xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd/
   Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443
   SSL negotiation with xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd
   Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
   Connected to HTTPS on xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd
   Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
   GET https://xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd/+webvpn+/index.html
   SSL negotiation with xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd
   Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
   Connected to HTTPS on xxxxx.xxxx.com.bd
   Please enter your username and password.
   GROUP: [GroupX1|GroupX2|GroupX3]:
   ```
4. Then I input group name. Then It prompts for username and password. 
   I provide both and it gets connected perfectly and works fine.

Now what I want is I want to add some kind profile if possible (which is possible in Cisco anyconnect in Windows machine) so I'll provide just password and it'll automatically connect.

So how can I convert my **anyconnect** profile to **openconnect** compatible profile and how can I use it?

Another question is, how can I create and run a shell script with a hardcoded password so that I'll just run the script and it'll connect to VPN?

I searched a lot but I've not been able to automate this.